# Can I do volunteer work while visiting for 2 months in Amsterdam?

Tags: international-travel, amsterdam, netherlands, volunteering, nicaraguan-citizens

I am planning to stay in Amsterdam for around 2 months to visit my brother. Is there any restriction to do non-paid volunteer work in Amsterdam. I hold a Nicaragua passport.

Comment: Usually you need a work visa even to legally do volunteer work, but I don't know if the Netherlands is usual in this regard or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. You are allowed to do *vrijwilligerswerk*, as it is called in Dutch, if you have a legal permit to be there. One exception is when you are awaiting a decision as to your status. [This site](http://www.vrijwilligerswerk.nl/?content=/77) contains Dutch-language information on the topic. Google Translate may be your friend.

However, you might need to be careful with insurances: [See here](http://www.vrijwilligerswerk.nl/?content=/74).

I don't know if you can get a visa through doing the volunteer labour, though.

I would recommend to contact the organisation where you want to do volunteer labour for practical issues.

Comment: I will just go as a tourist. Every time I stay for a little while in a place I like to do something good. I am not  looking to get a visa through volunteer labor. But I would like to know if there is any restriction in volunteer work as a tourist because I would hate to break the law in another country. Thanks for the info. I will check.

Comment: like all visa related questions for any country, it's best to contact an embassy or consulate for that country.

Comment: You're right. I will check and I will post the answer and experience.